# Drawing a rectangle but the color of the pen will not work

Tags: c#, system.windows.media

The error is on the line after `//Create pen`.  It states that System.Windows.Media.Color does not contain a definition for 'Black'. How do I fix this?

```
   public void DrawRectangleRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create pen.
        System.Windows.Media.Pen blackPen = new System.Windows.Media.Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        // Create rectangle.
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);

        // Draw rectangle to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
    }
```

How about this, and going back to scratch:

```
    public void DrawRectangleRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create pen.
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        // Create rectangle.
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);

        // Draw rectangle to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
    }
```

There is an error on `Black` saying System.Windows.Media has no definition for 'Black'. I got this example from [Graphics.DrawRectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx8yykw8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

How do I adapt it to my code?

Comment: What happened with the comments?

Comment: You're trying to use winforms code in a WPF application. I deleted my answer because I thought you had a winforms application.

Comment: Bring it back, ha  ha. It worked. Your last comment worked. But I have additional questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a winforms application, you should be using classes from the `System.Drawing` namespace; e.g. [`System.Drawing.Pen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.aspx).

The `System.Windows.Media` namespace contains classes for WPF applications.

I suggest you put `using System.Drawing` at the top of your file (and remove `using System.Windows.Media`), and then simply use `Pen` and `Rectangle` in your code.

Comment: I wish not to do that because it is a wpf application. So now what?

Comment: If I take out `using System.Windows.Media` and replace it with `using System.Windows.Media` it messes up my other code.

Comment: OK, then try just using `System.Drawing.Pen` and `System.Drawing.Color` inside your Draw function.

Comment: Your System.Drawing.Pen and System.Drawing.Color worked but now I have issues with `new Rectangle...` and `e.graphics...`. What do I need to add to fix that?

Comment: Also, does this mean I am using a wpf or winforms?

Comment: So I don't think you can mix wpf and winforms like that. If you want to draw shapes, you might want to start again with winforms only. If you want to stick with wpf, then you could just put a `<Rectangle>` in the XAML, I believe. Depends why you're doing this in the first place.

Comment: Is System.Drawing.Color and System.Drawing.Pen part of winforms?

Comment: Yes, WPF doesn't use anything System.Drawing, as far as I know.

Comment: So then I must be using winforms for the C# and WPF for the xaml? It's a GUI that uses XAML and C#. It was already created and I'm adding stuf to it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really.. You're using C# with WPF. If you're adding a rectangle to an existing WPF GUI, I think you just want to use `<Rectangle>` in the XAML.

Comment: And I can adapt my C# and/or xaml so it would add a rectangle on command of a button push?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you can: but I'm no WPF expert. You can try googling around for "add rectangle on button click wpf". E.g. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/47fc0a/create-shapes-dynamically-in-wpf/

Comment: @Question_Guy check my answer. I'm a little confused after read few comments. What you want to do finally?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)` you must set the background to `Transparent` in your `Window` object and override the `OnRender` method.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //--workaround: set the background as transparent.
    Background = Brushes.Transparent;
}
```

Then override `OnRender` method. A code assume the definition of: *_rectBrush, _rectPen, _rect*

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{       
    //--set background in white
    Rect bgRect = new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight);
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, bgRect);

    //--draw the rectangle
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(_rectBrush, _rectPen, _rect);
}
```

I hope it helps.

**EDIT:** Including an example:

The **XAML** part:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDrawing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Rectangle Painting" Height="350" Width="525"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonUp"
        MouseMove="MainWindow_OnMouseMove"
        Background="Transparent">
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfDrawing
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Point _p1;
        private Point _p2;
        private bool _painting;
        private readonly Pen _rectPen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 1);
        private readonly SolidColorBrush _rectBrush = new SolidColorBrush
        {
            Color = Colors.SkyBlue
        };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //--workaround: set the background as transparent.
            Background = Brushes.Transparent;

            //--Freeze the painting objects to increase performance.
            _rectPen.Freeze();
            _rectBrush.Freeze();
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            var rect = new Rect(_p1, _p2);
            Debug.WriteLine("OnRender -> " + rect);

            //--set background in white
            Rect backRect = new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight);
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, backRect);

            //--draw the rectangle
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(_rectBrush, _rectPen, rect);
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var p = e.GetPosition(this);

            Debug.WriteLine("MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonDown -> " + p);

            _p1 = _p2 = p;

            _painting = true;

            InvalidateVisual();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _painting = false;

            Debug.WriteLine("MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonUp");
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_painting)
                return;

            var p = e.GetPosition(this);
            Debug.WriteLine("MainWindow_OnMouseMove -> " + p);

            _p2 = p;

            InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }
}
```